# Passing form data not working in Express / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

Sorry if this is a remedial question, or an obvious error, but this is my first Node project.

Essencailly what I need to do is get a line of text that a user will input into a form on the front end. Unfortunately no matter what I do the result logs 'undefined'. I'm at a loss. I'll post the full code below, but the section that giving me trouble is:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.render('test');
});

app.post('/test',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body); 
});
```

the '/test' route is just temporary to test getting the form response (if for some reason that wasn't obvious).

My full HTML file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form id="myform" action="/test" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="mytext" />
        <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Any thoughts / help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full app.js file

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var twitter = require('./twitter.js');
var hue = require("./hue_control.js");

//Variable that control Twitter Calls
var api = 'statuses/filter';
var params = {slug:'test', owner_screen_name: 'REDACTED', skip_status: true};
var values = {};

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

hue.activate();
twitter.tweetStream(api, params, values);

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.render('test');
});

app.post('/test',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body); //you will get your data in this as object.
    console.log(req.is('json'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('tweets');
});

app.get('/tweets', function(req, res){
    res.render('home', {   
        profileImg: values.profileImg,
        userName: values.userName,
        screenName: values.screenName,
        text: values.text,
        timeStamp: values.timeStamp,        
        tweetScore: values.tweetScore
    });
});



//app.get('/tweets', function(req, res)

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing the **bodyParser** middleware in your express application which is why `req.body` is undefined.

If you are using Express 3.x, simply use the following line. BodyParser used to come bundled with versions prior to Express 4.0

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

If you are using Express 4.x,  You would need to require the body-parser module explicitly

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

and then use it in your app

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Issue is solved now. Really appreciate the help. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Roughly, this is what you need:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
...
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
...
```